# Вопрос по фрейму обратной формы. Не могу центрировать

Tags: html, iframe, форма

в общем проблема в следующем, решил испробовать обратные формы от Яндекса, а они во фрейме предоставляются. Вставил, поколдовал и получилось только так их вывести - https://spb.boostseo.ru/

Скриншот - http://joxi.ru/82Q096QcjZzM5m

Пробовал итак и сяк, уже не знаю что и делать, возможно ли как-то отцентрировать данные?

Comment: Я попробовал добавить к `iframe` класс `col-9` и это сделало отображение симпатичнее. Как возможное решение, могу предложить определить классы `col-lg-#`, `col-md-#` и т.д. для разной ширины экрана.

Comment: Опа, помогло. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Хотя не полностью, для ПК выстроил отлично, а вот мобильную версию не могу победить

Comment: Вы правы. Вы конечно можете уменьшить форму с `transform: scale(0.8);`, но это совсем не красиво. В таком случае, я бы поискал возможность не использовать шаблон Яндекс форм. Возможно у них есть API, через который можно будет создать то, что вам нужно, через ajax. К сожалению с Яндекс формами не знаком.

Comment: Я видел, что там есть "Кастом" яндекс формы, возможно там есть возможность сделать содержимое iframe адаптивным, относительно самого размера iframe.

Comment: Большой плюс форм Яши в том, что он всегда будет принимать письма и не будет проходить фильтры от хостинга и т.д., а то иногда бывает такое от моего хостера

Comment: Одно понять не могу, почему я с пк првоеряю адаптивность - все гуд - http://joxi.ru/YmEJBxaU0jnM62, если непосредственно с мобилы - то все плохо)

Comment: Можно использовать phpmailer чтоб не было проблем с получением писем и всяких блоков хостера

Answer (score 1):

iframe ставим например width:450px;
и ставим margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Сейчас попробую, просто по факту чего только не перепробовал

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению